# Time of response for Push in Git

Tags: git, repository, push

Does it take time to upload a project in a GIT repository using:

```
$ git push https://xxxxxx.git
```

I just did it, it says after a few minutes that it was done. And when I went to the specific remote directory, I'm still not finding it.

Does it take time to be submitted in the mentioned repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in general no, it is instant.

you probably are pushing to a bare repo and the files will BY DESIGN never appear where you expect them. read about bare repos: http://gitolite.com/concepts/bare.html

to distribute files via git, you need to pull from the target location, because pushing only really works with bare repos, and they do not expose the files directly.